# Adding NSObject to view - UIButton selector in NSObject causes crash

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, selector, nsobject

having a little issue in an ARC environment. Creating an NSObject that adds a view to a parent view - it's basically a 'popup class' that can handle some text and display it.

In a view controller it's instantiated..

```
CBHintPopup *popup = [[CBHintPopup alloc]init];
[popup showPopupWithText:@"test text" inView:self.view];
```

And the actual class files..

CBHintPopup.h

```
@interface CBHintPopup : NSObject {

}

-(void)showPopupWithText:(NSString *)text inView:(UIView *)view;
-(IBAction)closePopup;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *popupView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *blackImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *closeButton;

@end
```

CBHintPopup.m

```
@implementation CBHintPopup
@synthesize  popupView,blackImageView, closeButton;

-(void)showPopupWithText:(NSString *)text inView:(UIView *)view {

//CREATE CONTAINER VIEW
self.popupView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((view.frame.size.width/2)-(225/2),-146,225,146)];
self.popupView.alpha = 0;
self.popupView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

//CREATE AND ADD BACKGROUND
UIImageView *popupBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,225,146)];
popupBackground.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hintbackground.png"];
[self.popupView addSubview:popupBackground];

//CREATE AND ADD BUTTON
self.closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closePopup) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.popupView addSubview:self.closeButton];

//CREATE AND ADD LABEL
UILabel *popupTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22,25,176,93)];
popupTextLabel.text = text;
[self.popupView addSubview:popupTextLabel];


[view addSubview:self.popupView];
}

-(void)closePopup {
NSLog(@"HI");
}
```

Recieving the following once closePopup is called via pressing the button ('HI' is not printed)..

```
-[CBHintPopup performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x246b2fe0
```

I've tried retaining the button in non-ARC and a load of other methods but simply having no luck. Probably something real simple but i can't nail it. I've removed all the setting up of the labels and images etc to save some space, so ignore alpha's etc.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: try debugging to see on which line is it crashing

Comment: It isn't exactly crashing on a line as such, one of the objects involved (probably the button) has been deallocated.

Comment: Please post code where you are initializing CBHintPopup

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented the constructor for `CBHintPopup`,since you have called the constructor

```
[[CBHintPopup alloc]init];
```

you have to implement the constructor method like this

in .m file of CBHintPopup

```
-(id)init{

if(self == [super init]){

// do some initialization here

   }
  return self;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't include it in the code sample, but yes i do have this method (it doesn't actually do any initialization though).

Comment: change the -(IBAction)closePopup  to -(void)closePopup in both .h and .m file

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and found the crash you mentioned. I found a solution for fixing the crash.
I declared the `CBHintPopup *popup;` in the `viewController`'s interface. And changed this line

```
CBHintPopup *popup = [[CBHintPopup alloc]init];
```

to

`popup = [[CBHintPopup alloc]init];`

Everything worked fine for me. But I couldn't find the reason behind this. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, it did really help me. Though I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are retaining the object for class `CBHintPopup`.

I think the crash is coming because object of `CBHintPopup` deallocates. And hence the action method is not found.

Comment: Sorry, was halfway through changing both to IBAction - unfortunately still produces the same error. The entire project is ARC and has easily 10,000 lines of code, unfortunately i can't retain the object. I've tried flagging the CBHintpopup to be compiled as non-ARC (-fno-objc-arc) but it didn't work. Stumped!

Comment: Really? One, the documentation says that the return type should be void, two, IBAction is typedeffed to void. This "answer" is downright wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for clarifying. I thought that the return type in .h and .m should be the same. But it doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for it - instead of CBHintPopup being an NSObject, i simply made it a sub-class of UIView and added self to the parent view (instead of self.popupView). I wouldn't really call this a 'fix' though - more of an alternative method. Surely an NSObject can add a UIView (with a UIBUtton) to a parent view with no problems? Is this a bug?